# Public keys listed by both sudo gpg --list-keys and sudo gpg --list-keys but still not available?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

With `sudo gpg --list-keys`:

```
/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2021-02-09 [SC] [expires: 2026-02-08]
      D8E16B56B3FEFE0682D26EB5326A835E697B890A
uid           [ unknown] openmediavault plugin developers <plugins@omv-extras.org>
sub   rsa4096 2021-02-09 [E] [expires: 2026-02-08]

pub   rsa4096 2017-02-22 [SCEA]
      9DC858229FC7DD38854AE2D88D81803C0EBFCD88
uid           [ unknown] Docker Release (CE deb) <docker@docker.com>
```

and with `sudo apt-key list`:

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa4096 2021-01-17 [SC] [expires: 2029-01-15]
      1F89 983E 0081 FDE0 18F3  CC96 73A4 F27B 8DD4 7936
uid           [ unknown] Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (11/bullseye) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
sub   rsa4096 2021-01-17 [S] [expires: 2029-01-15]

pub   dsa1024 2010-03-14 [SC]
      0F6B CC17 C26B FADC 27F2  2100 7E7A 6C59 2EF3 5D13
uid           [ unknown] OpenMediaVault.org (OpenMediaVault packages archive) <packages@openmediavault.org>
sub   elg2048 2010-03-14 [E]

pub   rsa4096 2016-07-12 [SC]
      D675 06C8 78E0 8A94 FD7E  0094 2486 3F0C 716B 980B
uid           [ unknown] OpenMediaVault.org (OpenMediaVault packages archive) <packages@openmediavault.org>
sub   rsa4096 2016-07-12 [E]

pub   rsa4096 2021-01-17 [SC] [expires: 2029-01-15]
      AC53 0D52 0F2F 3269 F5E9  8313 A484 4904 4AAD 5C5D
uid           [ unknown] Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (11/bullseye) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
sub   rsa4096 2021-01-17 [S] [expires: 2029-01-15]

pub   rsa2048 2012-06-17 [SC]
      CF8A 1AF5 02A2 AA2D 763B  AE7E 82B1 2992 7FA3 303E
uid           [ unknown] Raspberry Pi Archive Signing Key
sub   rsa2048 2012-06-17 [E]

pub   rsa4096 2021-02-09 [SC] [expires: 2026-02-08]
      D8E1 6B56 B3FE FE06 82D2  6EB5 326A 835E 697B 890A
uid           [ unknown] openmediavault plugin developers <plugins@omv-extras.org>
sub   rsa4096 2021-02-09 [E] [expires: 2026-02-08]

pub   rsa4096 2017-02-22 [SCEA]
      9DC8 5822 9FC7 DD38 854A  E2D8 8D81 803C 0EBF CD88
uid           [ unknown] Docker Release (CE deb) <docker@docker.com>
sub   rsa4096 2017-02-22 [S]
```

That is, the keys `326A835E697B890A` and `7EA0A9C3F273FCD8` have both been imported successfully in both keystores.

But when I do `sudo apt update`, I'm still getting the following errors:

```
Err:10 https://openmediavault-plugin-developers.github.io/packages/debian shaitan InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 326A835E697B890A
Err:13 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://openmediavault-plugin-developers.github.io/packages/debian shaitan InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 326A835E697B890A
E: The repository 'https://openmediavault-plugin-developers.github.io/packages/debian shaitan InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Why can both keys still not be found?

Comment: does the apt source for those repos have `[signed-by=.....]` in them

Comment: The following files have [signed-by=...] in them:

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/omvdocker.list` with the following content:
`deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker.gpg arch=arm64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye stable`

and
`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/omvextras.list` with the following content:
`deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/omvextras.gpg arch=arm64] https://openmediavault-plugin-developers.github.io/packages/debian shaitan main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command fixed the issue for me:

```
sudo omv-aptclean repos
```